# Testing JDBC methods, including transactional aspect and connection closeds

Tags: java, testing, jdbc

I would like to define tests for JDBC methods for educational purposes. In particular, in addition to test whether the JDBC methods have the functionality required (I have seen that there are solutions such as DBUnit, etc), I would also like to check whether the methods verify specific requirements:
- if they consider transactional issues when modifying (setAutocommit(false)/commit/rollback)
- if they close the connection,
- etc.

I have not found any testing solution that checks whether spectific methods are invoked (methods such as the previous ones). The only thing that comes to my mind is trying to use a testing solution (such as DBUnit) together with AOP (for example AspectJ) for advising whether such methods are invoked.

Any other idea?
Thank you!

Comment: Did you try with `JUnit` ? This is not really made for testing JDBC functionnalities (this is not a unit) but this could do the trick for educational purposes.

Comment: Don't. Don't test the platform. Test your application.

Comment: I have already tried JUnit but I managed to test the functionality but not methods invocation.

Answer (score 0):

There are mainly three ways to do what you want to achieve:

#### Mocking JDBC

Popular choices are [mockito](http://site.mockito.org/) or [jmock](http://jmock.org/). Using jmock, for instance, you can write things like:

```
Mockery m = new Mockery();
Connection c = m.mock(Connection.class);
PreparedStatement s = m.mock(PreparedStatement.class);

m.checking(new Expectations() {{
    oneOf(connection).prepareStatement("test"); will(returnValue(s));
    oneOf(s).setFetchSize(10);
    oneOf(s).execute();
    oneOf(s).getUpdateCount();
    oneOf(s).getWarnings();
    oneOf(s).close();
}});
```

And then:

```
// Example code under test:
try (PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement("test")) {
    ps.setFetchSize(10);
    ps.execute();
    ps.getUpdateCount();
    ps.getWarnings();
}

// Finally, check if everything was called as expected.
m.assertIsSatisfied();
```

#### Implementing JDBC

Mocking APIs help you provide a mock implementation very easily, but you may wish to do much more than just mock the driver. In that case, you could actually implement JDBC:

```
class MyConnection implements Connection {
    final Connection delegate;
    public MyConnection(Connection delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }
    // ...
}
```

In this case, you can now intercept any method call and start collecting statistics and make assertions inside of the desired methods *without* modifying the underlying database interaction, as all JDBC calls will be delegated to the actual driver.

Many libraries, including e.g. jOOQ, ship with utilities for creating such proxying JDBC objects, see e.g. jOOQ's [`DefaultConnection`](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/blob/master/jOOQ/src/main/java/org/jooq/tools/jdbc/DefaultConnection.java). jOOQ also has an entire mock JDBC implementation, which can be seen in these articles:

- https://blog.jooq.org/2018/04/10/mocking-jdbc-using-a-set-of-sql-string-result-pairs/
- https://blog.jooq.org/2013/02/20/easy-mocking-of-your-database/

But I'm not sure if that's what you're after.

(Disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOQ)

#### Using AOP

By using a tool like [Javassist](http://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/), you can intercept certain method calls such as the desired JDBC method calls, and run additional logic before or after the actual call. This works in the same way as the previous approach of implementing JDBC, except you don't have to modify the application under test, so it is the least intrusive and simplest approach for simple validation tasks.

Comment: Thanks Lukas for your complete explanation. The point is that I would like to offer the least instrusive solution since I would like to design JDBC methods as usual, so I think that perhaps I could combine DBUnit with AOP.

Comment: @BeaPérezValle: All three approaches allow for using ordinary JDBC API. The "intrusiveness" manifests itself only in how easy it will be to patch the JDBC implementation behaviour. And that also depends on how much you want to patch.